# What header should be used at client and server if I want to send and receive gzipped json

Tags: nginx, gzip

Currently our server is sending json response with headers like below

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:83089
 Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
 Date:Fri, 31 Oct 2014 10:25:23 GMT
```

And as its not gzipped we are getting large json response. And I added header in ngnix proxy server's location block like below

```
 add_header Content-Encoding  gzip,deflate
```

Now I am getting error `net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`

What is the safe way to achieve gzip encoding.

Comment: did you do anything to actually make nginx gzip the content? just adding the header won't make the response gzipped, but it will make the client think that it is - hence the error

Comment: @codebox Could you please suggest us to achieve it.

Comment: see link in answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure nginx to [actually gzip the response](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html), just adding the header won't do this, but it will make the client think that the content it is receiving has been zipped and will attempt to unzip it - which explains the error that you are seeing.